# Copy - paste issue

Tags: vba, excel

I know I may sound really very silly to many of you As I present my issue.

What I am doing is I am trying to copy paste data from for excel sheet to my master excel sheet through a VBA code.

```
sht1.Sheets(1).Activate
Range("B58:L87").Copy
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Q1").Activate
Range("A1").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

sht2.Sheets(1).Activate
Range("B58:L87").Copy
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Q2").Activate
Range("A1").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
```

And continue the same for next two sheets. Q3 and Q4.

First time in my life I observed a strange thing which was happening while running the code.

When I run the complete code in one go without breakpoints (F5) 
-> Q1 and Q4 sheets are blank. Q2 and Q3 sheets are copied successfully.

But
When I run the same code step by step execution (F8)
-> All four sheets Q1,Q2,Q3 and Q4 are filled with the required data.

could someone please open my eyes to the unseen background process :)

I found the answer today.... That's after so many days :)

I moved the sheet , from 3rd position to the first position. But internally its (Sheet(1) which I didn't took into Consideration.... :)

Comment: Copy - paste ---> edited :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer today.... That's after so many days :)

I moved the sheet , from 3rd position to the first position. But internally its (Sheet(1) which I didn't took into Consideration.... :)

Comment: It helps to select sheets and ranges by name. Like `Sheets("Data")` and `Range("Cars")` for named ranges. Avoid `Range("A1")` and `Sheets(1)` because things _can_ move.

Answer (score 1):

If it works when de-bugging then it should work at runtime, unless you are selecting workbooks/sheets during the debug.

Try this instead of your current code.

```
For i = 1 To 4
   ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Q" & i).Range("A1:K30").Value = sht1.Sheets(1).Range("B58:L87").Value
Next i
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of Copy and Paste, try assigning the values directly

```
Dim src as Range, dst as Range
Set src = sht1.Range("B58:L87")
Set dst = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Q1").Range("A1")

dst.Resize(src.Rows.Count,src.Columns.Count).Value = src.Value
```